# C popen() changes the string

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, popen

I'm using `popen()` to run a shell command in my Ubuntu machine (16.04 LTS) and for some reason, `popen` changes the command string and then it runs the changed command string, resulting in an error, because there's no such command (it adds `/021/001` to the end of the string).

I run the same code on an equivalent machine with a different Ubuntu version (14.04 LTS) and `popen` doesn't change the command string and runs perfectly.

Any idea why this happens?

The code I'm running:

```
char* runShellReadCmd(char* command) {
FILE *fp;
int outputCurrentSize = 0, outputArrSize = READ_INITIAL_SIZE;
char readChunk[READ_CHUNK], *tmpOutputStrArr = NULL, *data = NULL;
fp = popen(command, "r");
data = (char*)calloc(READ_INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(char));
while (fgets(readChunk, READ_CHUNK, fp) != NULL)
{
    //  If string size equals to the array size, need to expand the array.
    if (outputCurrentSize >= outputArrSize) {
        outputArrSize *= 2;
        //  Re allocate array, save it in a temporary array.
        tmpOutputStrArr = realloc(data, outputArrSize * sizeof(char));
        //  If re-allocationg failed, stop and return NULL to indicate that a problem has occured.
        if (!tmpOutputStrArr) {
            free(tmpOutputStrArr);
            free(data);
            return NULL;
        }
        data = tmpOutputStrArr;
    }
    //  Concatenate the recently read 100 chars to the data arr.
    strcat(data, readChunk);
    //  Save current string length.
    outputCurrentSize += READ_CHUNK;
}
pclose(fp);
return data;
}
```

The command:

```
"/sbin/iwlist wlp2s0 scan"
```

funcs.c:

```
//  Runs a shell command using given command string and returns the output.
char* runShellReadCmd(char* command) {
FILE *fp;
int outputCurrentSize = 0, outputArrSize = READ_INITIAL_SIZE, elementsRead = 0;
char readChunk[READ_CHUNK], *tmpOutputStrArr = NULL, *data = NULL;
printf("%s", command);
fflush(stdout);
fp = popen(command, "r");
data = (char*)calloc(READ_INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(char));
// while (fgets(readChunk, READ_CHUNK, fp) != NULL)
while (elementsRead = fread(readChunk, sizeof(char), READ_CHUNK, fp) != READ_CHUNK)
{
    //  If string size equals to the array size, need to expand the array.
    if (outputCurrentSize >= outputArrSize) {
        outputArrSize *= 2;
        //  Re allocate array, save it in a temporary array.
        tmpOutputStrArr = realloc(data, outputArrSize * sizeof(char));
        //  If re-allocationg failed, stop and return NULL to indicate that a problem has occured.
        if (!tmpOutputStrArr) {
            free(tmpOutputStrArr);
            free(data);
            return NULL;
        }
        data = tmpOutputStrArr;
    }
    //  Concatenate the recently read 100 chars to the data arr.
    strcat(data, readChunk);
    //  Save current string length.
    outputCurrentSize += READ_CHUNK;
}
pclose(fp);
return data;
}

//  Returns the number of times the given substring appears in the given string.
int getNumOfMatches(char* string, char* substring) {
int count = 0;
char* temp = string;
while ((temp = strstr(temp, substring))) {
    count++;
    temp++;
}
return count;
}

//  Returns the first wlan device name thats available in the system.
char* getWlanDeviceName() {
int size = 0, i;
char* device, *tmpPointer, *deviceNameStartPointer;
char* str = runShellReadCmd("/sbin/ifconfig");
deviceNameStartPointer = strstr(str, WIFI_DEVICE_PREFIX);
tmpPointer = deviceNameStartPointer;
while (*tmpPointer != ' ') {
    size++;
    tmpPointer++;
}
device = (char*)calloc(size, sizeof(char));
tmpPointer = deviceNameStartPointer;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    device[i] = *tmpPointer;
    tmpPointer++;
}
free(str);
return device;
}
```

test_funcs.c:

```
//  Tests whether the wifi device can find wifi networks (at least 1).
int testWifi() {
int testOk = 0, length;
char* command, *output, *device = getWlanDeviceName();
length = strlen("/sbin/iwlist ") + strlen(device) + strlen(" scan");
command = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
strncpy(command, "/sbin/iwlist ", strlen("/sbin/iwlist "));
//strcat(command, "/sbin/iwlist ");
strcat(command, device);
strcat(command, " scan");
output = runShellReadCmd(command);
printf("%s\n", output);
testOk = getNumOfMatches(output, WIFI_NETWORK_START_STR) > 0;
//printf("%d", getNumOfMatches(WIFI_NETWORK_START_STR, output));
free(device);
return testOk;
}
```

Comment: `outputCurrentSize += READ_CHUNK;` this increment might be too large.

Comment: aside: `if (!tmpOutputStrArr) {
            free(tmpOutputStrArr);` : you don't need that `free`.

Comment: What are `READ_CHUNK` and `READ_INITIAL_SIZE`? You always add the maximum size of a line regardlessof the real size. Maybe you are better off using `fread` instead of `fgets` here.

Comment: I suggest using `const` in your function: `char *runShellReadCmd(const char *command)`.

Comment: can you `printf` the command before sending it to `popen`. What is corrupt? the command or the output? if it's the command, it's in some code that isn't here.

Comment: READ_CHUNK = 100 and the initial size (READ_INITIAL_SIZE) = 1000.

Comment: @pmg, I tried to initialize the command char* as const but the bug still occurs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, printf (before popen) prints the command as it should be (/sbin/iwlist wlp2s0 scan), its something inside popen that changes the command and executes it after its changed.

Comment: maybe your command buffer is undersized and overwritten by the subsequent `malloc` & `realloc` that you're using for your output. I doubt very much that `popen` has such a bug. Show us the code that calls your routine.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have edited the question and added the rest of the code.

Comment: Try `valgrind`, it will highlight the issue

Comment: When you piece together `command`, your `length` needs an extra byte for the null terminator. It may be worth considering `asprintf` instead of repeated `strcat`s plus handish allocation.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: Note: you can avoid all this string handling by using getc(). All your chunksizes will become one, and you wont strlen() anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
length = strlen("/sbin/iwlist ") + strlen(device) + strlen(" scan");
command = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
```

As suspected, your `command` buffer is too small (`length++` would be an improvement). You're missing the string termination. So the string termination is overwritten at some point when allocating some more memory in your `popen` loop and your command "leaks" since the null char char isn't where it should be anymore.

the fact that it works on some other machine is just luck. The memory allocation is different. But your code is still incorrect. That's why it's called *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You mean "string termination", not "line termination", right?

Answer (score 0):

Note: you can avoid all this string handling by using `getc()` in stead of `fgets()` . All your chunksizes will become one, and you wont need `strlen()` anymore:

```
char* runShellReadCmd(char* command) {
FILE *fp;
size_t size, used;
char *data = NULL;
int ch;

fp = popen(command, "r");
if (!fp) return NULL;

for(size=used=0; ;) {
        if (used >= size) {
                size = size ? 2*size : 100;
                data = realloc(data, size); // TODO : check return
                }
        ch = getc(fp) ;
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        data[used++] = ch;
    }
data[used] = 0;

pclose(fp);

// maybe a final resize here:
// data = realloc(data, used+1);
return data;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't need `used+1` for size check. The ternary should use the `?` as in `size = size ? 2*size : 100`

Comment: Yes, it does. For the final '\0', which will *always* be needed. Note: I updated the order a bit.

Comment: On second thought (and after having edited) : you are right. The `+1` was not needed, one character is added to the buffer for every character read (if you consider EOF to be a character)